# Validation error display is producing this 'undefined method `full_message' for :category:Symbol'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm following the [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views) to implement this, but I'm getting this error, and I'm not entirely sure how to fix it.

Error display in form:

```
    <% if @group.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_exp">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@group.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @group.errors.each do |error| %>
                    <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Controller create action: (I'm testing the error display on a new group form)

```
    def create
        @group = current_user.groups.build(group_params)

        if @group.save
            redirect_to user_groups_path(current_user)
        else
            render :new
        end
    end
```

Model validations:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :user
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :groups
    has_many :users, through: :groups

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false
    
end

class Card < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :group

    validates :front,:back, presence: true
end
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails guide is for `6.1`. Prior to that `errors.each` yielded `|attribute,error|` [Rails 6.0](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-each) and [Rails 6.1](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-each)

I am assuming you are below 6.1 based on your error in which case you want to use:

```
<% @group.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <li><%= message %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Then undefined method `full_messages' for #<Model id: nil, email: "", name: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Did you mean?  message :/